# Terminal Command to Zoom

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, zooming

I've been looking for this for a while, and I can't find it anywhere.

I need to be able to zoom (equivalent of ctrl + shift + '+') via the terminal. I've tried xdotool, but do not know how to get it to register '+' (or the = key).

This is very important and has been a life dream of mine. Now that I'm somewhat capable with Ubuntu, I feel that I can finally achieve this goal: I need to make an alias such that when I type in "enhance", everything zooms.

Comment: Have you tried using the [magnifier](http://askubuntu.com/q/164820/158442)?

Comment: With Kubuntu and Konsole: Ctrl++ and Ctrl+-.

Comment: What terminal are you using? What do you mean "zoom"? Increasing the text size or actually zooming?

Comment: I haven't tried using the magnifier, but I want to be able to type a command into the terminal and have it zoom (actual zooming). I'm using whatever terminal comes with Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm not looking for a keyboard shortcut—I want to be able to type something into the terminal

Comment: @AmagicalFishy the magnifier can be launched using a shortcut, so you can write an xdotool command similar to these to launch it.

Comment: With LXTerminal 0.3.0: `Ctrl`+`+` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`-`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`xdotool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdotool.1.html) (command-line X11 automation tool) commands to use are:

- Zoom in (AKA <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>)

  ```
   xdotool key Ctrl+plus
  ```
- Zoom out (AKA <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)

  ```
   xdotool key Ctrl+minus
  ```
- Normal size (AKA <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)

  ```
   xdotool key Ctrl+0
  ```

This won't work on Wayland ([`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355476/209677)).

Comment: You're the best, ever.

Comment: Did you make it work on Wayland, maybe with [wtype](https://github.com/atx/wtype)
or [ydotool](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool)?