# Is there a way I can zoom in gala window manager?

Tags: elementary, desktop-recording

I want to record a high res video of a zoomed in part of my screen.

Is there any way that I can increase the zoom level of my desktop?

Comment: Your question which is about Elementary OS like [this other question that you asked](http://superuser.com/questions/847975/how-to-fix-ppa-purge-error-release-distribution-for-package-was-not-foun) is off topic for here, on topic at [Unix & Linux Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note that this question is now on topic at http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting this to re-open as gala can be installed and used in Ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gala has a zoom plugin that is installed by default.

Default shortcuts are:

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>
<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>
to zoom in and out.

To check or modify the set values, have a look at `org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
sudo apt-get install xzoom
```

The usage is very simple, and exactly what I wanted:

- start in terminal  `xzoom`.
- place the window where it does not disturb you.
- "drag" you mouse cursor from within the window to the spot of the
  screen you want to magnify.

I found this [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164820/default-screen-magnifier) answer no 2, I don't know if elementary uses compiz so no 1 might not be valid.