# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Key combination "Ctrl +" will not enlarge window

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts

I have been messing around with a number of Ubuntu distributions (Up to 16.x LTS), and one particular issue which has been constant, is its inability to enlarge windows with the traditional key combinations.

Im currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with the English US keyboard set as the input method, and according to the shortcuts menu in settings, `Zoom in` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, which I has no effect on a window what so ever, and `Zoom out` by comparison, is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, which does exactly what it is meant to.

Curiously, zooming out is actually achieved with the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, with no use of either <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>, however I am certain that this is the relevant shortcut as altering <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (as it should be), appears to disable its functionality.

In short, my question is:

Although Zooming Out is achievable with the Combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, how do I 'Zoom in' In Ubuntu with the Key Combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> despite the misleading key combinations listed in settings?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ctrl+- and Ctrl+= aren't Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts but shortcuts for apps like Chrome, Firefox, etc. See if [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/164820/301745) is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out window enlargement and shrinkage is working absolutely fine, I just had to manually reset it from the relevant application's shortcut menu.

The default shortcut simply was not working until I reset it, at which point it worked properly, despite being reset to the same offending shortcut. Just a curious Ubuntu bug I'm sure.