# How to magnify full screen on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, vmware

[image]

Because of my poor eye, I need to magnify when I'm using desktop computer. My question is how to use magnifier on Linux? For example, Windows you can magnify the screen using shortcut 'windows key' + '+'. My ubuntu version is 16.04? Do I have to use a recent one?

I installed Compizconfig settings and enable magnifier but it doesn't magnify the side bar and upper bar. (I attached a photo of this problem for you guys to understand what I mean.)

Thank you, for always.

Comment: Did you try *Zoom* from *Universal Access* (in *Settings*)? You can use WindowsKey + ALT + 8 to turn it on and off... BTW, I am using 19.10 and I am not sure if it is the same in 16.04.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli it is!  Make it an answer ;)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you so much! However I guess I'll have to download 19.10, I can't find 'Zoom' on the Universal Access. I only see ' High Contrast', 'Large text', 'Screen Reader', 'Beep on Caps and Num Lock'

Comment: I have tested in 18.04 also and it works. (But, I do not have 16.04.) Have you tried the shortcut I mentioned?  See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164820/default-screen-magnifier