# How to zoom in while screencasting?

Tags: screencast, zooming

Is there a way I can zoom in where the cursor is, while screencasting, something like this:

[image: zooming in screencasting]

I presently using [kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/) on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit for screencasting. Good alternatives which allow this feature are most welcome, but should allow for audio recording as well.

**P.S.:**

1. The original video here:

   - [How to use google drive as music player](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6h5_8qnYR4k)
2. The screencaster I require should record video and not gif, the gif above is only for explaining what I need and is light-weight for AU.
3. I would like to have the screencaster have its own zooming ability and not application-specific zooming ability, i.e. I can zoom into Firefox using Ctrl+<kbd>+</kbd>. However, this won't work with all applications, I would like the screencaster to have this ability in itself or a generic zooming ability.

Comment: do you have wine sir? is it okay if i give you a recorder that works on windows, not linux?

Comment: Yes, I have wine-1.5.28 installed. If it works natively on wine, its fine. But applications not tested to run on wine wouldn't be a good solution IMO.

Comment: Why can't you just do it in post production(Using an editor like KdenLive)?

Comment: @AmithKK: That, it seems, is a bit tedious and not a clean way, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to proceed would be to use Compiz and its [Zoom Desktop](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Zoom) plugin.

> The Zoom Desktop plugin offers the ability to zoom in for an enlarged view of the screen. [..] Zoom Desktop works by causing the entire screen to zoom in, effectively giving you a more readable view of a portion of the screen.

Thus you can use `compiz` as a WM to zoom into portion of the screen while you're recording the screencast.

See also:

- [How to zoom in & zoom out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-inzoom-out)

Comment: I use Unity, so would using compiz be recommeded? I have read a lot of questions related to Unity+compiz crashes.

Comment: I couldn't really say as I use Xfce. I know people use Xfce with Compiz, so you could conceivably log into Xfce while doing the screencast, and switch back to Unity when done.

Comment: Unity (complete, not the 2D) uses compiz.

Comment: @Jobin: Doesn't Unity use Compiz as an effects system?

Answer (score 2):

In that video, they used Camtasia studio, the best recorder I have ever used. I spent so much time trying to find recorders that are close to that recorder. [Here's a discussion on how to install it on wine.](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/will_camtasia_studio_install_in_linux)

Anyway, I did not spend hour just to give that answer :)

You can use a web app, which looks great, [Screencast Matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/), I have java installed [this way](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html), I don't have Icedtead plugin, I do not know if it will work on OpenJDK. Just click record my desktop, it will start a Java app and follow your cursor.

There's also [Simplescreenrecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/), which you can install like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
# if you want to record 32-bit OpenGL applications on a 64-bit system:
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

You can choose to let the app follow the cursor. That app uses the codecs that you already have on your system, so you have to install the Codecs that you like.

In the picture above, Camtasia automatically zoom to where the cursor is, the other recorders do not do that, they follow your cursor, but you have to zoom, if you want to zoom you have to hold `Ctrl` + `+` or `Ctrl` + the `middle cursor` and they will zoom to where the cursor is. But at least, unlike Camtasia, they are free.

- [RecordItNow](http://recorditnow.sourceforge.net/) has everything that you need, it's a KDE app, the
  reviews on the software center are bad. I have not tried it, but
  [here's a demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed-RJMtNlms)
- [Here's a Sreencast O Matic demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/QapaCJzJZrEg), I hold the `ctrl key` +  middle
  cursor, but you can also use `ctrl` + `+`
- [Here's SimpleScreenRecorder demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/6hKi19Bl) *(please download the video and
  play it in VLC, just to make sure that it will work)* I zoomed the
  same way mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the method of installing screenr.com on Ubuntu in depth?

Comment: @Jobin screenr.com is a web app, no installation needed  and about camtasia, many people say it will work perfectly on wine

Comment: @Jobin if you're going for screenr, you do need to have java installed, not openjdk otherwise it might start complaining about icedtea

Comment: I have both java and openjdk installed, do I need to configure firefox for using a specific one? If yes, how?

Comment: @Fischer Please, take a time and provide more information, with detailed methods and procedures in order to write an *answer*. As it's currently written, it would fit better on a *comment* rather than as an *answer*. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucio thats what i am going to do

Comment: @Fischer: How do I zoom using Screencast Matic and SimpleScreenRecorder?

Comment: @Jobin you have to use `ctrl` + `+`, I will add a video to this answer showing you how to do it and will notify you soon :)

Comment: @Jobin I added the first demo, I'll edit my answer, to add another demo for SimpleScreenRecorder

Comment: The video gives this error when I server not found error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dPFqz.png even after trying multiple times.

Comment: @Jobin I will upload it elsewhere, don't worry i'll fix it :)

Comment: @Jobin I updated my answer, and I don't think you need the tool mentioned in the other answer, just a recorder that follow the cursor will do.

Comment: It uses the broswers zoom capability and not its own, so it would work when I try to zoom in when the cursor is on the address bar or even if I am working on the terminal(unless I use its own zoom capabilities, which coincidentally is ctrl + shift + +. Also, I won't be able to zoom when the application has no way of allowing me to zoom. Is there a way I can zoom without using application-specific zooming capability?

Comment: @Jobin I updated my answer, note that compiz doesn't seem to work on unity, if you want a really great one, I really encourage you to try the free trial camtasia studio on wine

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using camtasia over wine did not seem to work seemlessly, had issues with dlls over installation and Screen-o-Matic and SimpleScreenRecorder, as I said, works with application-specific zooming. RecordMyDesktop, also seems to use ccsm zooming, since I didn't see any option in itself for zooming. +1 for the efforts and the research! Thanks :)

Comment: @Jobin have you tried using winebricks to install the dlls?

Comment: @Fischer: I believe you mean using winetricks. Yes, tried installing dlls using this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine, but no respite, the error that props up is not helpful too. Tried googling, hardly any clues.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with compizconfig-settings-manager and compiz-plugins-main :

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-main
```

Then, open CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager) and enable the **Enhanced Zoom Desktop**

You'll be able to zoom in and out like in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3kyxjdLeBs). Zoom at 0:34