# How can I zoom one specific window in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, zooming, scaling

In my high resolution laptop display I defined the font to 230 dpi so everything looks fine but some apps that are running in java.

Is it possible to display **a specific desired window** scaled in double size?

For example: define that only the Jitsi-window has double size while all other windows stay system size.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-inzoom-out only shows How to achieve this in Unity on Ubuntu. This is not a duplicate! it is about KDE, not Ubuntu

Comment: That Unity link is about using a screen magnifier, which KDE also has. (It's called "zoom" and configurable from System Settings > Desktop Effects > All Effects > Zoom.) I presume that's not exactly what you want?

Comment: However, if you just want to permanently zoom a single window, it's [not possible](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=117175&p=294734#p294734).

Comment: as stated in the answer below, that would be only work around

Comment: @rubo77 Are you still looking for answers. The new answers might be different because KDE is now in version 5. Also are you looking for scaling or anything that fixes the size of the windows will do?

Comment: I'm not actively searching, but next time I try KDE i guess, I will 

Answer (score 1):

You can work around it with the resolution switcher as in the answer here: [Fix scaling of java-based applications for a high DPI screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/fix-scaling-of-java-based-applications-for-a-high-dpi-screen)

It automatically changes the resolution based on the app in focus