# Launch a program at double the zoom

Tags: unity, dpi, zooming

I've got a high DPI screen and certain applications (Skype, Gimp, Inkscape) show tiny icons.
The rest of the system seems ok, so I'm just wondering if it's possible to launch a program zoomed in 2x, e.g. using some accessibility functionality?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/615754/72216 The first version of the script is what I would recommend in this case. It would work best however if the application ran on a dedicated workspace.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, good hack, but I don't want the rest of the system to change too.