# Font looking Ugly after changing size and not recovering

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, tweak

I tried to change the size of my fonts. Now the font is looking ugly. I can't change to previous form. See how ugly it is looking!
[image: sample error]
[image]

I am using KUBUNTU 18.10. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To improve your fonts you need 2 things:

1) Choose fonts

You can [search online for fonts recommendation](https://linuxhint.com/best_fonts_ubuntu_linux/) or download the [ubuntu fonts](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/).

Some fonts are [`high dpi` fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) and they render with more pixel at high resolutions.

I personally use [use this fonts configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9kQ1.png), but before I was using `DejaVu Sans Mono` which is `high-Dpi` compatible

2) Use High-Dpi fonts on a High-Dpi screen

If you are running 4k (or also on a normal screen), you can open [`tweak` tool](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and select `font` tab to increase the [scaling factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwQep.png).

Increasing the scaling factor will increase your font size and change the windows proportions. Everytime you increase the `font-factor` you need to increase your screen resolution or decrease the font-size.

Even if I had a full-hd monitor (`1080p`, not `4k`), I was able to increase my resolution up to 5000pixels with `xrand`

Ubuntu is not really `high-dpi` compatible like `mac`, and many application will have `UI` issues (I experienced problems with `chrome`, `mozilla`, `spotify` ..etc.)..

Some application will display too small at `4k` resolutions and some other apps will display too big at normal resolution, high-dpi and smaller text sizes.

If you want to try [this discussion explains how to configure high-dpi for every ubuntu application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen), while this other discussion explains [how to increase resolution with xrand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/fix-scaling-of-java-based-applications-for-a-high-dpi-screen)

If you fall in love with high dpi and the beautiful fonts, you may consider switching to a Linux Distribution compatible with `High-Dpi`