# Kubuntu 20.04 has several GTK Issues

Tags: kubuntu, gtk, filezilla

I did a fresh Kubuntu 20.04 install and I could already solve some little issues. But I can't figure out how to solve the following issues with two necessary GTK programs.

- phpStorm (version 2018.3) starts very slow and the GUI is lagging a lot. Even a simple tab switch takes 2 seconds and CPU goes to 100% for every simple action. Besides the lagging all font sizes look good.
- Filezilla shows opposite symptoms. The GUI is very responsive but the font size of the directory trees is very tiny here.

Before I had Kubuntu 16.04 installed and both programs don't had any of these issues. I would appreciate any help to get both programs running smooth again.

Comment: It would help to know how you installed each program. Also, sometimes if you start a program from a console (CTRL+ALT+T by default on Ubuntu) by typing the name and pressing Enter then you'll get extra information. You can paste that info to a service like pastebin.com and share the link here. FWIW I tested install of Filezilla using `sudo apt install filezilla` and it works fine for me on Kubuntu20.10.

Comment: Thanks for these hints. phpStorm was installed by running it's own installer. Filezilla was installed via apt as you described. Starting it from the command line returns follwing output: https://pastebin.com/E06B04uN
I made a screenshot to better highlight the issue https://pasteboard.co/JNeoxXA.png It only affects the font size of the treeviews and transfer queue, all menu fonts are fine.
The KDE font settings are set to 144 DPI. It's exactly the same setting as before in Kubuntu 16.04 but probably it could have to do something with this?

Comment: I have the same text for FileZilla in the console output; none of it seems relevant. But I can't see the problem with your screenshot? Looks fine to me??

Comment: The font size of the treeviews and transfer queue is too small. It does not reflect the KDE font settings (Noto Sans 10) like the menu font. It is something smaller. When working longer with Filezilla it is too small for my eyes. In Kubuntu 16.04 it had the same font size

Comment: WRT Filezilla I've looked at it now on MS Win 10 too, I think this is just the apps design. You might be able to [change the display resolution whilst you use that app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526484/fix-scaling-of-java-based-applications-for-a-high-dpi-screen) in order to magnify the display. But I don't think there's much else you can do except ask the app makers/file a bug. Good luck, don't forget to post back if you find a solution.