# Ubuntu Gnome: screen "zoomed" in and stuck

Tags: gnome, compiz, display-resolution

I tried switching from Gnome (Metacity) to Ubuntu (default) because I wanted to try something with Unity. The screen appeared WAY zoomed in, with the Gnome menu bar still at the top, and the side dock momentarily visible, then disappeared. I tried switching back and logging in, and the desktop is screwed up: menus and icons about 4x the size they should be, the upper menu bar almost useless.

The screen resolution reports as 1920x1080, but is actually 1/4 of that, zoomed into the upper left quadrant. `xrandr` also reports 1920x1080, but if I use `--scale 2.0 x 2.0`, it refreshes at the correct resolution (but the menus, cursor, etc. are all wrong).

Other users are still fine; it's just my account.

Any ideas how I can "reset" this back to its correct size, etc.?

Comment: Further investigation: a screenshot came out 840x545, even though the control panel and xrandr both claim the desktop is in 1920x1080 and changing to other resolutions has no effect.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Fore people accidentally enabling zoom the shortcut to enable/disable [is by default Super+Alt+8](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084153/349837)

Answer (score 3):

What a mess...

I got stuck in this after kids mash the keyboard.

This worked for me:

**Settings -> Universal Access -> Seeing -> Zoom.**

Switch it to off.

[image: zoom setting]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up restoring all my configuration files (ie those files and directories in my home directory whose names begin with a `.` or have paths beginning `~/.`) from a backup and that fixed it. But I never figured out what caused it.