# Screen become black after upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: 17.10

Sir I have upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04. After that the system began to start normally.. then the screen become black I can't get it how to resolve this problem.... plz can anyone help me to get rid of this problem... I am using dell vostro laptop . And intel i3 processor with intel graphics card HD 520 (skylace GT2)

Comment: @An0n How's that issue with "*using Nvidia or AMD binary drivers*" applicable here?

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into recovery mode.
From there continue the software upgrade:

```
dpkg –configure -a
```

After that try to load Ubuntu with a normal boot.
Finish Software Updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: +1 When I got the black screen, I went to terminal mode by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1. Then I logged in and I did `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then `sudo shutdown -r now`. And the black screen is gone now. But there was an issue with display as it was scaled up which was rectified by https://askubuntu.com/a/1052273/440833