# After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, display is like zoomed

Tags: display, 18.04

Last night I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04. After the upgrade when I logged into the account I had been using the display is like super zoom.

Kindly assist with solution.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: I have an issue like this in the current 20.04.  At the login screen and after login menus are enlarged.  If I goto settings->Display and set screen to 200% then revert, the screen displays as expected/normal.  Still haven't figured out how to fix this so it doesn't happen initially.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem, but figure it out that Zoom was active. Just go to Universal Access in Settings and disable Zoom.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have no such an option as Zoom in my Universal Access settings. I had to switch the desktop manager to Unity in order to be able to view my desktop properly. With the Zoom on, I can't see much on my screen.

Comment: It worked! :) btw does anyone know why is zoom on by default?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan In Ubuntu 18.04 I could find 'Universal Access' in Settings under 'Region and Language' ... and Zoom is the 4th option under 'Seeing'

Comment: I had the Universal Access it in the top-right. I reinstalled drivers twice before finding this answer. This is a very bad default setting.

Answer (score 5):

I have nvidia GeoForce GTX 1080 graphics card.

I went to `Software & Updates` and then to the `Additional Drivers` tab and selected what is given in the below image. It installed the drivers after which I rebooted and it was fine.

[image]

Comment: A version of this answer worked for my system with RTX 3080 Ti. After I was making some Nvidia/Cuda related changes (I wanted to do a fresh install so I purged all Cuda/Nvidia related stuff) on restart my graphics got messed up (The zoom effect which is the subject of this question).

I went to Software and Updates/Additional Drivers and initially the interface was blank. After a few seconds, I picked the top of the list meta-package from an nvidia-driver and hit apply changes.

Graphics were back to normal after reboot!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if your resolution is the highest avaible and is the same as your graphic's card. If no just change to highest.

If it is the highest just download from Ubuntu Store Gnome Utils (It may be called as Gnome center as something kike this) and change display scaling from 1.0 to e.g 0.75).
This should help you.

Comment: I tried to change  resolution to 800*600 using tab, it shrink the screen but still showing zoomed.

Comment: What's your graphic card's resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Your screen seems to be ultra magnified. I think it's due to a configuration problem. To solve it, try to find the Settings button (normally should be on the left). Then click on 'Universal Access' and find the Zoom setting. You can reduce the magnification of your screen to 1, but I recommend you just disable the zoom (at the top right part of the screen).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where this zoom setting is suppose to be? I've clicked all the menus in All settings > Universal access with no sight of any Zoom-like option (that would be turned on).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have a laptop with an external 23" monitor and used to work fine in ubuntu mate 16.04. When I updated to ubuntu mate 18.04 everything was like zoomed. 
The issue was that it was not detected properly. I run

export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0

then reboot and the monitor was detected right! This was my source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390362

My problem was also described here: [Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting monitor size properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066879/ubuntu-18-04-not-detecting-monitor-size-properly/1099435#1099435)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after switching to a new external monitor. As the screen had changed I had to update the configuration by using `xrandr --auto` which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and none of the above solutions seemed to help. I knew it was a GPU driver problem, but I found finding the right version of my drivers in the PPA confusing, I couldn't install any additional drivers in Software & Updates, and the zoom setting in Universal Access was already disabled.  If your GPU is made by NVIDIA and you're on 18.04LTS, this [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) was what helped me figure it out. I'll summarize the main part:

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

to find the name of the drivers you need, and then, assuming you agree with the output,

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

will install the drivers. Alternatively, you can also do

`sudo apt install nvidia-xxx`

where xxx is replaced by whatever number is output by the first command. In my case, after restarting my computer, the problem was fixed and I had a nice, much more high-def display.

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly my problem some days ago. After around 5 hours trying to solve it and thinking the worst about Linux or Ubuntu :-/ (I tested almost every posted solution and reboot my pc more than 15 times without result, including updated the kernel, sw/systems updates, sw changes, config files edition, and etc...); **I realized in my case that actually my problem was not**. During installation, the TV was turned on, and the TV is connected to my computer through the HDMI port. So the system configured the TV as the first display and the embedded monitor (of my all in one PC) as the second one. So the system got configured for my TV instead of my actual monitor. As the TV was being used to watch stream media, not as a monitor (input:HDMI), I did not realize this until several attempts and research.

The solution was to use shortcuts keys to zoomed out[1] the screen and then I was able to understand what happened, access system configuration, and configure my primary monitor as the main one.

This problem was for me at the end a bit funny...

1. [How to zoom in & zoom out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out)

Answer (score 0):

i equally had the same issue after ubuntu update, and just followed setoff zoom in general setting. To accès it, type zoom in general setting.