# Ubuntu 23.04 not auto-detecting external screen resolution

Tags: display-resolution, 23.04

I'm facing an ongoing issue with my Ubuntu 23.04 OS where it fails to auto-detect the resolution or size of my external Samsung 32" screen. As a result, everything appears zoomed in on the Samsung screen, while my built-in 15" screen works fine. I've tried various troubleshooting steps, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. Can anyone suggest potential solutions? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1099435/875665, but didn't solve my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]