# Is there a magnifier for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: accessibility, zooming

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.  I am half blind and used to love the compiz config tool and the way it could be configured to the keyboard.

Does 18.04 have anything that comes close to this?

Thanks.

Edit...  I think my question differs in the way that, the solutions here all seemed to apply to versions prior to 18.04.  I tried the options in the link, which included Unity Tweak Tool, Gnome Shell and CompizConfig Settings Manager.  All the windows and options were there as per the screen shots, trouble was none of the short cut keys actually did any thing.

Edit 2..  After installing dconf Editor, I followed the link and enabled Screen Magnifier as per the instructions, and left the defaults. Nothing really happened, so I looked for it in 'Show Applications', and found something that needed to be downloaded and installed, and came up with a window labeled xzoom.   It seems to run oblivious to any of the settings in the dconf Editor, even after being disabled.  I'm a bit confused and am wondering if it is even the right one.

Comment: Check out this link: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/how-to-enable-screen-magnifier-in-ubuntu-18-04-19-04/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zoom in & zoom out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out)

Comment: Thanks kenn, I will look into that.

Comment: I noticed that link wasn't secure