# How to smoothly desktop Zoom-in/out with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on iMac late 2014?

Tags: macosx, zooming

I know there are currently a bunch of requests on this subject, e.g. [How to zoom in & zoom out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out) - I have an iMac late 2014 with recognized GPU and decided last week (march 2021) to install and use Ubuntu 20. I need of course also the nice zoom-in/zoom-out feature which is so smooth on OSX. Unfortunately, no matter what tool I try to download/install/customize so far, no reaction on continous desktop magnification. The standard fractioned magnification works but gives a very bad quality on zooming.

I tried (with no success):

CCSM (compiz config manager) - latest version 0.9.14

Unity-Tweak-Tool - latest

Tweaks - latest

No way to attach mouse wheel (buttons 4 and 5) to any of the super/alt/shift/ctrl and/or combinations. I get no reactions and no error warnings.

I tested GPU use with test programs getting good results and the GPU seems hence to be recognized by Ubuntu 20.

More precisely Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit GNOME 3.36.8 and X11 on Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz × 8 with AMD® Radeon r9 200 series

Any (further) idea please what can I do in order to use this imac with screen-Desktop maginification like in OSX?

Comment: In my case it is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit GNOME 3.36.8 and X11 on Intel® Core™ i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz × 8 with AMD® Radeon r9 200 series

Comment: Well, I did both indeed, but what I have to observe here is that instead of getting a solution, a hint, I get here ethics!!! Are you accumulating poins inside this portal? Never mind I can even renounce to get here some practical solution since I do guess the work to be done (and disclosed) will take some time. Thanks.