# ALT + Mousescroll for Zoom on Desktop like XFCE on Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, zooming

On XFCE there is the in-house function for zoom the whole screen by using ALT and Mousescroll. I love this function but changed to Ubuntu 22.04. Is there a package or an extension in extension-manager to enable this zoom function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zoom in & zoom out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82398/how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out)

Comment: No there is only keyboard shortcut exmaples. I want to zoom with ALT+MouseScroll and thats not possible in the solutions

Comment: Then file it as a feature request for GNOME as the MouseScroll Zoom doesn't exist. https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests